# NOT NULL constraint django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a **cart** model using **ForeignKey** relation with **User**.

My `mall/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class products(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='detail of product')
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class cart(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name
```

I am getting a error like this:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__mall_cart.user_id
```

whenever I am trying to `migrate` it. Its showing the same error if I am migrating the `products` class alone  as well
.
I have provided `null=True` as well as `blank=True` and the `superuser` is created with the name of `admin`. What is issue here?

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: How are you trying to create cart?

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko i did, and during migrate I got the error.

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov a user with ``ForeignKey`` with ``User``.

Comment: @nipan09 update the question with the actual code resulting in error, something like Cart.objects.create(...)

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov I have edited the question, please have look at this. Earlier this error was not there with the ``products`` class.

Comment: Help me out with this.

Comment: Do you currently have an cart objects in your database? If yes do all of them have a user?

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov I have deleted the last migration and set only ``null=True`` in ``user`` field and it worked. Thanks for your help.